# What is the hot side of a polarized power cord?

Tags: electrical

I’m making a power cord for a radio with a c7 polarized end. Which is the hot? Inside the cord is a white insulated wire and wrapped around that is bare wire.

Comment: I would guess the insulated wire is hot and neutral is wrapped around it; but you can easily test this (continuity) with a voltmeter and you should probably do that anyway.

Comment: All I have is the female end of a cord. One side is square and the other round. I’m wondering which to make hot?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375678/why-is-this-power-cable-sometimes-polarized-and-sometimes-not may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The squared off side is the neutral/grounded conductor. So, the rounded side is the hot/ungrounded/live conductor.

If it's polarized, it's not *really* a C7. The standard does not include those. If it did, you could just refer to the standard for which one goes where. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320

Answer (score -1):

The fact that there is a **bare, uninsulated wire** wrapped around the white, insulated one, indicates that this *might* be a [resistor line cord](https://ez.analog.com/ez-blogs/b/engineering-mind/posts/the-burning-issue-with-resistor-cords-and-how-to-solve-them) that contains internal resistance wire to lower the current to series-string tubes (valves). Check the resistance of the bare wire -- if it's greater than one ohm, then it's either a resistor cord or one with a dangerously thin wire.

- If it's an ordinary cord, I'd replace it with any similar cord. Likely the bare wire is neutral, but I'd not want to continue using it.
- If it's a resistor cord, consider carefully what to do.

  Resistor cords were known for **starting fires** and were known as "curtain burners", and the metal chassis to which they were attached were likely **electrically "live"**. Depending on how the device is wired, there may be *no* safe way to connect the chassis ground!

  If the radio is being restored as an antique, you would not put a grounded plug on it. And if there is *any* chance this radio was to be *used* by an uninformed person, then two changes should be made:

  - An isolation and voltage-dropping transformer should be added (i.e., to the voltage of the series filaments).
  - Since this is *not* double insulated, a three-wire grounded cord should be used, connected to the chassis.

Comment: This is a **rather large leap of logic,** given that I have multiple examples of transistor and IC radios with nary a tube in them that have polarized but otherwise similar to a C7 connectors (or in some cases actual C7 unpolarized connectors.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, it's not the C7 plug that indicates it a resistor cord, but **the bare wire inside, uninsulated**.